# How to accomplish the below PHP script in node.js.

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, express

Here I am trying to bind the parameters of the insertOrganisation function. that is var=organisation, and var = parentId, to the values which am inserting into my sql database using the query below (insertQuery).

```
function insertOrganisation($organisation, $parentId) {

    // validate incoming parameters
    // I assume you are using PDO and have established a successful database connection
    $dbh = new PDO(......);
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO organization (org_name, parent_id) VALUES (:name, :parent_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE parent_id = VALUES(parent_id)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($insertQuery);
    $stmt->bindValue(':parent_id', $parentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $organisation->org_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Question is: How can i bind the parameters of the insertOrganisation() function, that is:  var = organisation, var = parentId to the values inserted by the query(insertQuery), that is (org_name, parent_id) in Node.js. Thanks in Advance

Comment: just a wild guess, `by writing the Javascript`.  When you have an issue with that, you can then try to ask a proper question.  In the meantime, please read the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

 var con = mysql.createConnection({
     host: "localhost",
     user: "yourusername",
     password: "yourpassword",
     database: "mydb"
 });

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO organization (parent_id, org_name) VALUES ?";
    var values = [
        [parentId, 'org_name'],
    ];
    con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
   });
});
```